# create a next cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, parent, detach

I am trying to create an infinite cycle of elements using the following code:

```
$('div').click(function(){
   move = $(this).detach();
   $(this).parent().append(move);
});
```

but it just seems to be removing my objects, rather than moving them to the end of the list in order to create the cycle

Where are I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().append(this);
```

should be sufficient. It will automatically remove the element and place it where it belongs.

Answer (score 4):

`move = $(this).detach();`

That line removes the element from the DOM.  Once you have done this it has no parent.  Just remove this line all together.